# R, sample() two specific columns

Tags: r

I have the table "d" and want to take 10 random entries. From those 10 random entries I just want to show columns a and b. How do I have to modify the following code?

`sample(d, 10, replace=FALSE)`

Furthermore I want to show it in a table, so I want to put it into an data.frame
but `data.frame(sample(d, 10, replace=FALSE))` doesn't seem to work neither.

Comment: We will need to see an example of `d` and the desired result

Comment: `d[sample(nrow(d),10), c("a","b")]` You're in trouble if `nrow(d) < 10`, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sample` selects from a vector. So below I have taken the selected 10 rows using `row.names`. I use that in conjunction with `which` so that it subsets the data selecting rows that appear in the `sample`.

```
df <- data.frame(a = rnorm(100), b = rnorm(100), c = rnorm(100))
df
|          a|          b|          c|
|----------:|----------:|----------:|
| -0.2871389| -3.3284312|  1.1407268|
|  1.0332958| -0.3941396| -0.5673642|
|  0.3818575|  0.3572952| -1.0359738|
| -0.8893199|  0.3631301| -1.7498299|
|  0.6397421| -1.2466878| -0.6821477|
|  1.7704890|  0.2878294|  1.0452640|

sample_df <- df[which(row.names(df) %in% sample(row.names(df), 10, replace = FALSE)),c(1,2)]

sample_df
|   |          a|          b|
|:--|----------:|----------:|
|38 |  1.1299788| -0.5821954|
|42 | -0.7098492|  0.5000970|
|45 |  0.3411080| -0.3986854|
|46 |  0.1327252|  1.1115524|
|62 |  0.2457775| -0.5019835|
|74 | -0.1426126|  0.7491008|
|78 | -0.5061047| -0.3007340|
|92 | -0.4990604|  0.1078757|
|97 |  0.5888083| -1.8678351|
|99 |  0.9145843|  0.4139922|
```